# How to create service that will go to a specific folder on the phone, android

Tags: android, android-service

I wish to create a new service that will start setting-sonyericsson-conectivity.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent i=new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SONY_ERICSSON);
```

probably something like this, but this is not the correct I assume?